# need help for 3D plot by datetime series in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

x = np.zeros((2, 24), dtype = 'datetime64[h]')
x[0,  : ] = np.arange('2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', dtype = 'datetime64[h]')
x[1,  : ] = np.arange('2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', dtype = 'datetime64[h]')

y = np.zeros((2, 24), dtype = 'datetime64[D]')
y[0, : ] = np.array(['2020-02-27' for i in range(24)])
y[1, : ] = np.array(['2020-02-28' for i in range(24)])

z = np.zeros((2, 24))
z[0,  : ] = np.arange(24)
z[1,  : ] = np.arange(24)

surf = ax.plot_surface(x, y, z)

plt.show()
```

I want to plotting 3D likes below:

[image]

But appear error message below:
"TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta' "

How should I to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there is a [`plot_date`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot_date.html) function to operate on `datetime.timedelta`, in your case you cannot use that function in 3D. Instead, you can create an int/float array to represent that data, by converting the dates to numbers using [`matplotlib.dates.date2num()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num). Then you can set the tick labels in whichever format you want. I used the default `timedelta` below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.dates as dates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

x = np.zeros((2, 24), dtype = 'datetime64[h]')
x[0,  : ] = np.arange('2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', dtype = 'datetime64[h]')
x[1,  : ] = np.arange('2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', dtype = 'datetime64[h]')
# convert the datetime to num
xt = [[dates.date2num(d) for d in xi] for xi in x]

y = np.zeros((2, 24), dtype = 'datetime64[D]')
y[0, : ] = np.array(['2020-02-27' for i in range(24)])
y[1, : ] = np.array(['2020-02-28' for i in range(24)])
# convert the datetime to num
yt = [[dates.date2num(d) for d in yi] for yi in y]

z = np.zeros((2, 24))
z[0,  : ] = np.arange(24)
z[1,  : ] = np.arange(24)

surf = ax.plot_surface(xt, yt, z)
# set x labels as diff in hours
ax.set_xticklabels(x[0]-min(x[0]))
# set y labels as the two dates 
ax.set_yticklabels([y[0][0],'','','','',y[1][0]])
plt.show()
```

The result is as below.
[image]